# React setState based on prevState is not working properly for me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a simple image application using react. On initial load it will try to hit an api to get the list of images as response. I am appending the response to the existing image array and increment the page, so next the api request will be like this :

```
https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=cars&page=1 // first time

https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=cars&page=2 // Second time

https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=cars&page=3 // third time
```

So on and so forth. The problem I am facing is: I have two state variable one for the images and one for the page as shown below. Both the images array and page is not updating every time when I make the call.

```
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
```

In the following code I am trying to update the state variable

```
const fetchImages = async (searchTerm, currentPage) => {
    console.log('fetch images');
    let config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Client-ID'
      },
      params: { query: searchTerm, page: currentPage }
    };
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos',
      config
    );
    const newImages = [...images, ...response.data.results];
    setImages(newImages);
    setPage(page + 1);
  };
```

The whole app code is in https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7cvbll?file=src/App.js

Not sure what I am doing wrong please help me out...

**Updated**

As per the suggestion i have modified the setters using a callback.but this time the images array is working fine and page count is not updating even with the callback approach

```
  const fetchImages = async (searchTerm, currentPage) => {
    console.log('fetch images');
    let config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Client-ID'
      },
      params: { query: searchTerm, page: currentPage }
    };
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos',
      config
    );
    const newImages = [...images, ...response.data.results];
    setImages(prevState => {
      return [...prevState, ...response.data.results];
    });
    setPage(page => page + 1);
  };
```

Comment: You're creating a closure around the initial `images` state and then always resetting it back to that. Instead you'll want to access the current state by using a callback in your `setImages()` call. `setImages(prevImages => [...prevImages, ...response.data.results]);`

Comment: I tried the callback solution for the images it is working fine, but for the page it is not working. i have updated the code also

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7cvbll?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using mutator functions for your state setters:

```js
setImages(images => images.concat(response.data.results));
setPage(page => page + 1);
```

You need to have your function references as stable as possible (using useCallback) and update your listeners when function change:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('event', listener);
  return () =>  window.removeEventListener('event', listener);
}, [listener]);
```

in your file the "page" value in the function called by scroll event is never updated due to that.

I've made a fork with changes which is working for me:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ny3nxd?file=src/App.js

Comment: i tried this but page count is not updating even with the callback

Comment: Hi @Apolo it is working fine thanks. But what exactly the issue is in the previous code.want to learn more on this

Comment: so basically, at the start your scroll listener function is created when `page` = 1. It is attached to window.scroll events via useEffect. Every time scroll event is fired, this **initial** function reference will be called. What you want is to call a function created after the update of `page` and has the right value, so you need to update the listener when your onScroll listener is updated. Adding the listener to the array of the deps for the useEffect mean the effect is executed when the listener reference change, thus updating the window.onscroll listener

Comment: btw, without useCallback function reference will change at each render. If you add useCallback you specify an array of deps, if any change your function will be updated and you will have a new reference.

Comment: Thank you so much. That make sense